# Close the WPF dialog when one clicks on a button inside the WindowsFormHost

Tags: wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

I have a WPF dialog, that hosts a windowsFormHost control, with something like this

```
<Window x:Class="WPFSort.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFSort"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto"
                          Margin="87,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
            <local:SimpleWinControl />
        </WindowsFormsHost>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And for the SimpleWinControl  , it is a WinForm control. When `button 1` is clicked, I want

1. The WPF dialog to be closed
2. And the data `importantdata` to be "pass out" to the WPF form that calls the WPF dialog?

   ```
   public partial class SimpleWinControl : UserControl
   {
       public SimpleWinControl()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public object importantdata;

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         //how should I write the close and pass the importantdata out

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example add a property to your WinForms control that exposes the `Button` control:

```
public partial class SimpleWinControl : UserControl
{
    public SimpleWinControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Button TheButton { get { return button1; } }

    ...
}
```

Give the WinForms control an `x:Name` in your XAML markup:

```
<WindowsFormsHost HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="87,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
    <local:SimpleWinControl x:Name="winFormsControl" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

...and hook up to the `Click` event of the `Button` in the code-behind of your WPF dialog window:

```
public partial class Dialog : Window
{
    public Dialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        winFormsControl.TheButton.Click += (s, e) => this.Close();
    }
}
```

The window that opens the dialog could then access the `importantdata` field once the `ShowDialog` method returns:

```
private void ShowDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dialog d = new Dialog();
    d.ShowDialog();

    object importantData = d.winFormsControl.importantdata;
}
```

Another option may be to raise an event from the WinForms control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2(v=vs.90).aspx